# Mockito does not recognize class

Tags: java, mockito, cdi, weld-junit5

I tried to user weld-junit5 with mocking a class. 
I mock the class because i want to know how often it will be called.

But each time i try to Mockito.verify() this mocked class it throws a "NotAMockException"

The Intellij Debugger is validating the field as: `"Mock for MessageService, hashCode: XY"`

I already tried to add my testclass into the WeldInitiator but it dont want to work.

"MessageService" is a real class, not an interface (a Interface wouldn't work either)

[Docs](https://github.com/weld/weld-junit/blob/master/junit5/README.md#adding-mock-beans)

```java
@EnableWeld
class GameServiceTest {

  @WeldSetup
  public WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator.from(GameService.class, GameCache.class,
                                                 /** Some More **/,
                                                 GameServiceTest.class).build();
  @Produces
  @ApplicationScoped
  public MessageService createMessageServiceMock() {
    return mock(MessageService.class);
  }

  @Inject
  private MessageService messageService;
  @Inject
  private GameService gameService;

  @Test
  void handleRunningGames() {
    this.gameService.handleRunningGames(null, mock(Session.class));
    // This will throw a org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException
    Mockito.verify(messageService, Mockito.times(1)).writeMessage(any(), any());
  }
}
```

I expect, that the Injected MessageService is a real mock, on which i can call every Mockito function, but it seems not so.

Do I anything wrong, or what is the proper way to do this?

I think I just resolved this problem:

```java
  private static final MessageService messageService = mock(MessageService.class);

  @Produces
  @ApplicationScoped
  public MessageService createMessageServiceMock() {
    return messageService;
  }
```

Comment: The problem is that `weld` wraps stuff into proxy objects. You can use the solution mentioned in this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981660/get-the-real-object-from-cdi-proxy) but that is rather ugly.

Comment: I guess you are probably better off testing you classes without using `CDI`/ `weld` in the unit tests and instead inject the dependencies using `mockito`'s `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotation.

Comment: Thanks @second I see that this seems not to be the best way to do testing, but at the moment its ok.

I added my solution.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging and remember it for future questions (I removed the leading tags)

Answer (score 4):

To give some background, the way it works is that Weld lets Mockito create the desired object and then takes that as a contextual bean instance.

However, in CDI any bean that has normal scoped needs to have a proxy that is passed around instead of that instance. So what your producer actually does (because it is `@ApplicationScoped`) is create the object, store that in the context and then also create a proxy and pass around that proxy instead. The proxy is a different object (a delegate with no state) that "knows" how to get reference to the actual instance.

So what happens is that proxy gets injected into the field and you are checking the proxy object with `Mockito.verify()` call. Obviously, the proxy isn't the mock itself and so it fails. As user @second suggested, Weld offers an API to unwrap the proxy and get the contextual instance. I would argue that the API isn't "ugly", it is just a thing users shouldn't mostly care about but sometimes you cannot avoid it.

You could avoid having proxy by using some of the pseudo scopes which are `@Dependent` or CDI `@Singleton`. With that it should work as well and so long as it's for tests, replacing application scoped with singleton should work.

As for your workaround, I do no see how that solves anything - it is basically the same producer and because of the scope it will only be invoked once, hence the static field will make no difference (as there will be a singular call to mock creation). Have you changed something else than that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using `@Singleton` but this will throw following Error because the services are `@Stateless`: `Pseudo scoped bean has circular dependencies. Dependency path`

Answer (score 1):

As a user of JUnit 5 + Weld-JUnit myself, I am using the following pattern. The reasons are those explained in the answer by [Siliarus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57475165/2764255).

```
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import ...

@EnableWeld
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) // (1)
class GameServiceTest {

    @WeldSetup
    public WeldInitiator weld = WeldInitiator.from(GameService.class, GameCache.class,
                            /** Some More **/,
                            GameServiceTest.class).build();
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped // (2)
    @Mock              // (3)
    private MessageService messageServiceMock;

//  @Inject            // (4)
//  private MessageService messageService;
    @Inject
    private GameService gameService;

    @Test
    void handleRunningGames() {
        this.gameService.handleRunningGames(null, mock(Session.class));
        // (5)
        Mockito.verify(messageServiceMock, Mockito.times(1)).writeMessage(any(), any());
    }
}
```

Explanations:

1. I am using the Mockito extension for convenience
2. You do not really need to give it application scope
3. The `@Mock` annotation is handled by the `MockitoExtension`. Again, this is only for convenience, you could create the mock yourself in a producer method.
4. You do NOT need to inject the mock service; you have the `messageServiceMock`! The injected thing here will be the Weld proxy, as explained by Siliarus.

   It is fun to describe this injection a bit more: If the bean is `@ApplicationScoped`, i.e. "normal-scoped", CDI has to inject a proxy. If you use this proxy instead of the actual mock, you will get the exception. If you follow my advice from (2) and leave out the `@ApplicationScoped`, the bean will be dependent-scoped and the mock is injected directly. In this case you could use the injected field, but why bother?
5. Use the mock directly.

Comment: Thanks for that answer but unfortunately this is working in my case. If i remove @ApplicationScope I get following issue `Pseudo scoped bean has circular dependencies. Dependency path` which seems to be right (Services are `Stateless`. When adding `@ApplicationScoped` I am getting `Cannot return null from a non-dependent producer method` (I know why).. and if a dont use @Mock and declare it directly it is telling me that none method was called.

Comment: Hmm the "Cannot return null" error is caused probably bacause the Weld JUnit extension executes before the Mockito extension. You may have luck by: (a) Placing `EnableWeld` *after* `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` (b) using `@ExtendWith({MockitoExtension.class, WeldJunit5Extension.class})`. I am using `@EnableAutoWeld`, before `@ExtendWith(Mockito)`.